# grails gsp with <input type="datetime-local" when posted to controller fails validation and wont save

Tags: grails, bootstrap-4, form-submit, gsp

grails v3.3.9, and bootstrap.

I have been wrestling with getting grails, fields and bootstrap to work happily when processing Java LocalDateTime.  Nearly there but not quite ...

I have created a /fields/localdateTime/_widget.gsp like this

```
<div class="input-group date col-sm-8"  >
    <input id="${property}-label" name="${property}" type='datetime-local' class="form-control" value="${value}" placeholder="<empty>"/>
    <div class="input-group-append" >
        <button class="btn btn-icon-fixed-width btn-outline-secondary btn-block" disabled aria-disabled="true" type="button" >
            <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

this uses bootstrap

when the edit action is triggered on show view, it correctly renders this field in the edit form, and fields plugin, reads the _widget.gsp and renders the field correctly.

The control (in chrome) seems to work ok, and i can select a date, and set the time in the input field

however when i submit the update button, the data posted back to the update action **does not** pick up my changed date value, but rather sends the original value that was in the domain object before hand.

worst however is that the controller gets the object passed to it and in the debugger the domain object arrives with correct id and what *looks like* a valid LocalDateTime in the debugger (albeit the original and not the edited value )

```
def update(BootstrapTest bootstrapTest) {
    if (bootstrapTest == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }


    if (!bootstrapTest.validate()){
        println "object delivered to update action from edit form doesnt validate "
        respond bootstrapTest.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }
```

however whilst it looks ok - when you try and validate it fails

and whats rendered on the browser is **"Property ldtProp is type-mismatched"**.  What is wrong with the LocalDateTime validation?

I can create grails bootstrap data and save to db so its not the domain class nor validation when saving that way - its just when the record is delivered to the controller that it breaks

I've tried an equivalent field with LocalDate - and that seems to work and validates correctly, and i can save the object posted to the controller update action.

This is just so frustrating can any one elucidate on what this fails and what to do to correct it ?

this last bit has me stumped.

in order to wrestle with what fields plugin is actually doing, i've got a private version here [private plugin copy with adjusted content](https://github.com/woodmawa/bsfields)

i've run run this as private clone of fields plugin because i couldnt watch what was happening under the covers, so this has a number of libraries, style sheets imported back in so i can do in situ debug.  various /*fields/xxx/**gsp defined to render the bootstrap form /display bits.

Answer (score 1):

Blimey, another nest of worms...

First, the `<input type="date"` or `<input type="datetime-local"` as interpreted by chrome renders the browser value as 'mm/dd/yyyy' for date and for datetime-local as mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:(ss:SSS - greyed out )

When you provide a `value="string"` it ignores your string - so you have to pass the *actual* value into input as value="${value}".  If you convert that into a formatted field before, then it gets ignored, and default template is shown.

Next problem - when you submit the form the value sent to your params block is actually a ISO formatted string - not a LocalDateTime etc!

So when Grails tries to load the record from the db for you and inject it into your controller, its already tried to update the record once.

The problem is that this has fired a validation which has already failed.  So when you get the domain object in your 'Update (Domain xxx) {...}' method the object already has its errors set.

So I tried to convert the strings sent in params to LocalDateTime, LocalDate, and then update my domain object in the controller - but they failed when using validate() as the preexisting errors where already there.

So I had to clear the errors first, then convert the params strings to the right Java date types and then update the domain object and then validate. This then is happy.

So the controller action now has to look like this

```
def update(BootstrapTest bootstrapTest) {
    if (bootstrapTest == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    LocalDateTime ldtProp
    LocalDate dtProp

    if (bootstrapTest.hasErrors()) {
        bootstrapTest.clearErrors()
        try {
            ldtProp = LocalDateTime.parse(params.ldtProp?.toString()) //ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
            dtProp = LocalDate.parse(params.dtProp?.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) //ISO_LOCAL_DATE
            bootstrapTest.ldtProp =  ldtProp
            bootstrapTest.dtProp = dtProp
            bootstrapTest.validate()
        } catch (ex) {
            println "exception $ex.message"
            respond bootstrapTest.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }
    }


    try {
        bootstrapTestService.save(bootstrapTest)
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        respond bootstrapTest.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    } ...
```

So clear the errors first - then correct/convert the params map format to domain object format thats ok for the domain class property (or define set method in the domain that accepts a String and does the conversion internally)

Once you do that the re validation succeeds this time and your controller/db updates start to work.

Without using custom date pickers etc ( and for scaffolding that's overkill ) you have to live with the present data handling for

I have not tried this on another browser but Chrome is my 'normal' dev browser and behaves as indicated above.

--PS - additional trace. In the background when the Domain object is located and loaded, grails seems to have a convertor from String to DateTime, because i built a setDtProp (dt) setter - and this is called with converted value before the object is delivered to the controller - which is why I saw the dtProp change originally described, but no change to the ldtProp (where I have added a setter also in the domain object).

So however Grails is doing the injection process it doesn't do it for LocalDateTime as string from the browser (but it does put string into params for you ), but it will call a setter for LocalDate.    Either way when the domain object is loaded its errors() has been set - so you need to handle this from the controller as shown.  Trying to fix with setters in Domain class doesn't work for LocalDateTime as your setter is never called!

This can only to be handled in the controller once the object is injected as shown above, as I'd started to do in the first place.

Comment: How the browser renders it is irrelevant... and probably locale dependent. It seems to take ISO datetimes as input and output which is what matters. I would suggest the cleanest way to handle this in grails is with the @BindUsing syntax on the domain object, since unfortunately, grails doesn't natively support setting datetimes with an ISO datetime. However the bigger problem is that Firefox and Safari don't support datetime-local, which seems extremely unfortunate to me.